# Show that $\int_{R}x_n(t)y_n(t)dt \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(x_n)_{n \in N}$ a sequence in $L^1(R)$ which converges weakly to 0 and let $(y_n)_{n \in N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^\infty(R)$. I have to show that $\int_{R}x_n(t)y_n(t)dt \rightarrow 0$

My idea was to use the fact that $(y_n)$ in Cauchy, hence convergent.

Also maybe using that $[L^{1}(R)]^* \cong L^{\infty}$ and $x_n$ converges weakly to $0$ it holds that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x^*(x_n) = x^*(0)$.

But as i mentioned just ideas, would appreciate a well explained result.

Answer (score 3):

Any weakly convergent sequence is bounded, so there is some $M>0$ such that $\int|x_n|<M$ for all $n$.  Fix $\varepsilon>0$.  Since $(y_n)$ is Cauchy, there is some $N_1\in\mathbb N$ such that $\|y_n-y_m\|_\infty<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$ whenever $n,m\geq N_1$.  Fix $m\geq N_1$.  Since $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $0$ (and as you've noted $[L^{1}(\mathbb R)]^* \cong L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$), there is some $N_2\in\mathbb N$ such that $\left|\int x_ny_m\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ whenever $n\geq N_1$.  Put $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$.  If $n\geq N$, then we have 
$$\left|\int x_ny_n\right|\leq\left|\int x_n(y_n-y_m)\right|+\left|\int x_ny_m\right|\leq\|x_n\|_1\|y_n-y_m\|_\infty+\left|\int x_ny_m\right|<\varepsilon,$$
(the first inequality is just the triangle inequality, the second is Holder's, and the third is the established bounds) and the result follows.

Comment: I forgot about Holder in this case - and I swear I had this as an exercise years ago! Well-written.

Comment: Thank you! I feel most students get an exercise like this at some point in their real analysis courses.

Comment: @Aweygan +1, nice proof. However, can't we dispense with the epsilons? bounding exactly as you did and taking the limit of n<m should give you the desired results (once we note that Cauchy sequences in $L^\infty$ are bounded)

Comment: @qbert Thanks!  I'm not sure that would work.  Because then you're starting with a $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, and either picking up a $\lim_{n,m\to\infty}$ along the way, or things don't tend to zero.  Maybe you had something else in mind, but the way I'm seeing it, things don't pan out.

Comment: @Aweygan here was my idea: I'll take $m=n+k$, and we take $|y_j|<M$ for any $j$ (using completeness of $L^\infty$ and boundedness of convergent sequences) then in the limit as $n\to \infty$, the first term dies, and the second does with the additional bound $|\int x_ny_{n+k}|\leq M|\int x_n|$

Comment: @qbert Oh I see.  In that case the first term is fine, but the inequality $|\int x_ny_{n+k}|\leq M|\int x_n|$ does not hold in general.  What does hold is $\int |x_ny_{n+k}|\leq M\int|x_n|$, but this does not tend toward zero, at least not in general.  And bounding $\int x_ny_{n+k}$ is the same thing as proving the result, by re-indexing.

Comment: @Aweygan im confused about why the first should not hold, it's bounded by what you wrote: $|\int x_ny_{n+k}|\leq \int |x_n y_{n+k}|$ by the triangle inequality. You're right, I think for that to go to 0 you need to invoke weak convergence in $L^1$, taking the functional $f\mapsto \int_\mathbb{R} f$. I don't mean to bug you! just wondering if this works

Comment: @qbert Not bugging, I'm reading a good book and it's hard to pull away.  But once you use the bound $\left|\int x_ny_{n+k}\right|\leq M\int|x_n|$, the map $f\mapsto \int |f|$ isn't a functional, and you would have to invoke norm-convergence, which we don't assume.